# Clearing cache failed to add the new CSS properties

Tags: theming, caching

For Drupal 7, I'm using

- Cache pages for anonymous users
- Compress cached pages.
- Aggregate and compress CSS files.
- Aggregate JavaScript files.

The problem is when I update the CSS code for one of my CSS file, the code doesn't show in my page.

I have tried to **Clear all cache** and even run **cron**, but the new CSS code doesn't get added to the cached and minified version of my CSS.

The only workaround is just to disable "Aggregate and compress CSS files."

Any thought on this will be helpful.

Comment: Does timestamp on your aggregated CSS changes? Can your site regenerate them if you manually delete `/sites/*/css/*`?

Comment: Does timestamp on your aggregated CSS changes? I dont see the timestamp somewhere.If i delete all the cached files my self they regenerate but the css then have some errors.

Comment: Check it via ftp / sftp / ssh - most filesystems keeps track of ctime and mtime so you should be able to see when they was created and modified.

Comment: Thank for your hint. The file was last edit/generated July 18, 2013

Comment: What matters if it's earlier or later than you edited your original CSS files. And can your site regenerate aggregated ones once you purge them manually?

Comment: I have tryed in past to just delete them but when i go back to my site the seemed the css lost something(the site dont was 1290px boxed layout and some more strange thinks. And i go back and restore the delete cached files.(180 cached css) i think this is too much :/

Comment: and you're editing the right css file ?? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your Drupal is not able to write inside `DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/*/files/css` directory. That's why aggregated CSS files are not renewed. Consult your sysadmin to correct permissions and allow Drupal full write access inside `DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/*/files` and all subdirectories, that should solve it.

Comment: the drupal can write the dir. I have deleted all files from DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/*/files and the drupal recreates the css files....but it just dont get the new css rules inside them...can i manually add them?

Comment: OK, so this is different problem than it looked like. In comments under question you told that CSS disappeared, right? So now I'm confused. And you can't manually edit aggregated files, your edits will disappear in days if you will.

Comment: Well after i manually delete all cashed css ,some css rules like the width and some another css-rules disappeared. After my delete attempt #2 my css seemed ok but the new css rules just dont show...i can't figure out why the new rules dont apply...

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the parent directory holding your stylesheets to make sure your updates are writeable to those files.

Answer (score -1):

Try the [AdvAgg module](https://drupal.org/project/advagg/). Go to the status page and check to see if AdvAgg complains about anything.